# Alignment of text equidistant from all sides (centre alignment)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to fit a few lines of text in the centre of a subplot in the following manner.

[image: example]

The length of the text is not fixed it may vary. Not so successful in achieving what I needed.  This is what I tried.

```
 ax11 = fig.add_subplot (gs[3:11:,:]) 
 ax11.text(0.0, 0.5, '\n'.join(wrap(note, 130)), fontsize=8, 
           ha='left', va='center', multialignment='left', wrap=True)
```

**Updated**

```
note = "This is a test Physician note. This note is written to check the text wrapping in the Physician Diagnosis / Interpretation. Sentences are repeated to check the amount of data that can added in the subplot without the data getting printed outside the margin of the subplot. Along with wrap the textwrap is used, to split the data into sentences of 120 characters, each line is separated using the new line characters"

ax11 = fig.add_subplot(gs[3:11:, :]) 
ax11.text(0.0, 0.5, '\n'.join(wrap(note, 130)), fontsize=8, 
          ha='left', va='center', multialignment='left', wrap=True)
```

I need to centre the text inside the box.

Comment: Could you please show the text as code sample? Also what exactly do you want to do? You want to center the text **box** or center the text **inside the text box**?

Comment: Thanks for adding details. What is the `wrap` function? `textwrap.wrap`?

Comment: Did my solution work? If yes, please upvote and accept, if no please provide more detail.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center the text **inside the text box**, simply set `multialignment='center'`:

```
ax11.text(
    0.0, 0.5, '\n'.join(wrap(note, 130)), fontsize=8, 
    ha='left', va='center', multialignment='center', wrap=True)
```

Since you are already explicitly wrapping the input text with `'\n'.join(wrap(note, 130))`, the additional argument `wrap=True` is, in my opinion, unnecessary and just causes ugly additional text wrapping. Setting it to `wrap=False` (or omitting it) will improve the text formatting to only use your defined **explicit line breaks**:

```
ax11.text(
    0.0, 0.5, '\n'.join(wrap(note, 130)), fontsize=8, 
    ha='left', va='center', multialignment='center', wrap=False)
```

Comment: I did try the solution you suggested. But that results in the text getting centre aligned. I need the text to be justified.

Comment: You wrote that you want the text centered in the box: "I need to centre the text inside the box." Thus I answered your question such that the text is center aligned. Now you say that you want it justified. Why didn't you ask for justified text?